# UDF for concatenating elements of two arrays VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Suppose there are two 1D arrays each of them contains 3 elements as follow

```
A   1
2   3
B   C
```

How does one concatenate the two arrays into a single array with elements

```
A1
23
BC
```

It's easy to do that in sheet operation by using either & or CONCATENATE function, but how to do this in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the array and combine them into a third:

```
Sub foooooo()
Dim arr1() As Variant
Dim arr2() As Variant
Dim outArr() As Variant
arr1 = Array("A", "2", "B")
arr2 = Array("1", "3", "C")

ReDim outArr(UBound(arr1))
For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    outArr(i) = arr1(i) & arr2(i)
Next i

Debug.Print Join(outArr, ",")

End Sub
```

Comment: It might be beneficial if you needed to use it more than once, to create a function.  `Function concatArrays(arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant) As Variant`

Comment: @MichaelRusso I will let the OP do that, I was just giving proof of concept.  As the OP did not include any of his own code it is hard to infer exactly what is wanted and what type of output and to where.  So I gave the backbone on which the OP can derive any need.

Comment: I wasn't implying that you didn't give a complete response, because you did.  I just wanted to give another option.  It didn't need another answer because you had already answered.